# Status of the Network Interface Card in UWP

Tags: windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

I need to find the status of the Network interface card in UWP. I did not find any way to get the status. Is it possible in UWP to get the status of NIC?

Answer (score 0):

You are able to get it from `NetworkInterface`

```
bool isNetwokAvailable = NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable();
```

or  subscribe on event `NetworkInformation.NetworkStatusChanged`

```
NetworkInformation.NetworkStatusChanged += NetworkInformation_NetworkStatusChanged;
```

[NetworkInterface Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface(v=vs.105).aspx)

[NetworkInformation Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br207293)

**EDIT:**

Ping something

```
bool async IsNetworkAvailable()
{
        HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.CreateHttp(ApiRootUrl);
        request.ContentType = "application/json;charset=UTF-8";

        try
        {
            await request.GetResponseAsync();
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
}
```

Comment: No it behaves in same way when i disable adapter and in disconnecting the LAN

Comment: Hmm, it's really always returns `false`. It's strange. I'm can advice to ping something. In my app I request my backend.

Comment: @HariKiran In my experience, some adapters may affect the result of this API method. Could you please check your Network Adapters? (Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections) And Dmitry's suggestion is the right way to check NIC info in UWP app, was the NetworkStatusChanged event fired normally?